# Simple and fast shell remote

Tags: c++, shell, ssh, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I'm looking for a fast and easy method to remote shell to my raspberry pi (with out password require and encrypted like ssh ) because my project require running simple command to raspberry pi many times / a second, any suggest ideas? 
update: Method must be used in C++

Comment: Look at using `ssh` in master mode (`ssh -M`). This creates an SSH connection to a machine with a socket that can be used by future connection attempts, bypassing the need to reauthenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raw TCP sockets. It's hard to get simpler than that.

Server side:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo /tmp/fifo.$$
netcat -l -p 12345 < /tmp/fifo.$$ | sh - &> /tmp/fifo.$$
rm /tmp/fifo.$$
```

- Create a named pipe
- Listen on port 12345. On connection, read from the pipe and write to stdout.
- Redirect stdout of netcat to a shell that writes to the pipe.
  Basically this creates a netcat <> sh duplex.

Client side:
    netcat ip.address 12345

- Takes commands on stdin
- Output on stdout

The client can also be implemented in C++ by using sockets. Boost.Asio iostreams are pretty straightforward. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/iostreams/daytime_client.cpp

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s("ip.address", "12345");
s << "command\n";
s >> output;
```

Comment: I have a problem in serverside, I copy your code to abc.sh, and run it `./abc.sh` but after a while it's not up ( I nmap it and no appear port 12345) please help!